# Prevent inline elements from line breaking within their group

Tags: html, css

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jaWjB/1/

The line break happens in between the second image and its label. I want to make any `<span class="group">` element behave like an incompressible block, so that the line breaks will happen in between the blocks but not within them.

This would mean the above fiddle would be laid out as

```
[img]label
[img]label
```

instead of

```
[img]label[img]
label
```

but, if there is enough width available, it should display like this

```
[img]label[img]label
```

At the moment I can only do this with tables. Is there another way?

Comment: See my updated answer for a display: inline solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your css

Edited so that they are inline with enough width

```
p {
width: 10ex;
border: thin solid red;
display:inline;
}
​span{
display:inline-block;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add `display:inline-block` to your `.group` class, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jaWjB/7/

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3NSZ/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `span: after` selector. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jaWjB/9/). It provides a very elegant solution the the problem by inserting a line break after every `span` element.